# How to make HTTP Post request with JSON body in Swift?

Tags: json, swift, http, post

I'm trying to make an HTTP post request with a JSON body :

How to be able to add an NSdictionnary to the HTTP request body.

Here is my code, it doesn't seem to work properly.

```
var entry1 = Response(IdQuestion: 6510,IdProposition: 10,Time: 30)
var entry2 = Response(IdQuestion: 8284,IdProposition: 10,Time: 30)
Responses.append(entry1)
Responses.append(entry2)

let list = Responses.map { $0.asDictionary }

let json = ["List":list,"IdSurvey":"102","IdUser":"iOSclient","UserInformation":"iOSClient"]

let data: NSData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(json)

NSJSONSerialization.isValidJSONObject(json)

let myURL = NSURL(string: "http://www.myserver.com")!
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: myURL)
request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

request.HTTPBody = data
let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
    data, response, error in
    println(response)
    // Your completion handler code here
}
task.resume()
```

Answer (score 297):

Try this,

```
// prepare json data
let json: [String: Any] = ["title": "ABC",
                           "dict": ["1":"First", "2":"Second"]]

let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: json)

// create post request
let url = URL(string: "http://httpbin.org/post")!
var request = URLRequest(url: url)
request.httpMethod = "POST"

// insert json data to the request
request.httpBody = jsonData

let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
    guard let data = data, error == nil else {
        print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "No data")
        return
    }
    let responseJSON = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
    if let responseJSON = responseJSON as? [String: Any] {
        print(responseJSON)
    }
}

task.resume()
```

or try a convenient way [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire)

Comment: very beautiful. added version with latest Swift syntax (seems to change every week)

Comment: @JoeBlow - please post your alternative as a new answer. It's too radically different to be an edit to this one.

Comment: hey @ChrisF !  how are you.  - it's totally normal to post each new version of SWIFT.  i'll give you links to 500 questions with "new swift version" edited in.  best to put it back, thanks.

Comment: @JoeBlow - I'm not sure that there is a community consensus on this, so I have rolled back the edit again and asked about this on Meta.SO: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/339024/are-edits-that-insert-swift-3-code-into-existing-swift-2-answers-acceptable

Comment: no worries.  personally, there's no way I'll ever bother adding new answers in such cases; nor will I micro-manage whether the new code "exactly matches" the old code.  so that's out on SO

Comment: hi @nRewik, if you're still on the site, for goodness sake can you edit the answer to Swift3 syntax.  to save you typing, it is in the edit history

Comment: For me adding this helped: 
`request.setValue("\(jsonData.length)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")`
`request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")` [Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43095344/3411787)

Comment: This is dangerous unless you also set the content-type header properly: `request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")`. Otherwise, it does the type for forms. The super-common ExpressJS + bodyParser setup will get incorrect results for this **only sometimes, depending on the content**. So this breeds silent failures.

Comment: Yes my ExpressJS + bodyParser setup was not working correctly. Thank you very much for that sudo.

Comment: I get a question, for the 2nd line, could I use `JSONEncoder().encode` instead?

Answer (score 67):

**Swift 4 and 5**

`HTTP POST request` using `URLSession API` in Swift 4

```
func postRequest(username: String, password: String, completion: @escaping ([String: Any]?, Error?) -> Void) {

    //declare parameter as a dictionary which contains string as key and value combination.
    let parameters = ["name": username, "password": password]

    //create the url with NSURL
    let url = URL(string: "https://www.myserver.com/api/login")!

    //create the session object
    let session = URLSession.shared

    //now create the Request object using the url object
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "POST" //set http method as POST

    do {
        request.httpBody = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters, options: .prettyPrinted) // pass dictionary to data object and set it as request body
    } catch let error {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
        completion(nil, error)
    }

    //HTTP Headers
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

    //create dataTask using the session object to send data to the server
    let task = session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { data, response, error in

        guard error == nil else {
            completion(nil, error)
            return
        }

        guard let data = data else {
            completion(nil, NSError(domain: "dataNilError", code: -100001, userInfo: nil))
            return
        }

        do {
            //create json object from data
            guard let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers) as? [String: Any] else {
                completion(nil, NSError(domain: "invalidJSONTypeError", code: -100009, userInfo: nil))
                return
            }
            print(json)
            completion(json, nil)
        } catch let error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            completion(nil, error)
        }
    })

    task.resume()
}

@objc func submitAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
    //call postRequest with username and password parameters
    postRequest(username: "username", password: "password") { (result, error) in
    if let result = result {
        print("success: \(result)")
    } else if let error = error {
        print("error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}
```

**Using Alamofire:**

```
let parameters = ["name": "username", "password": "password123"]
Alamofire.request("https://www.myserver.com/api/login", method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: URLEncoding.httpBody)
```

Comment: Was looking for this "URLEncoding.httpBody" for a while, thank you

Answer (score 49):

**HTTP Post in Swift capturing the errors**

```
let json = [ Activity.KEY_IDSUBJECT : activity.idSubject, Activity.KEY_RECORDMODE : "3", Activity.KEY_LOCATION_LONGITUDE : "0",Activity.KEY_LOCATION_LATITUDE : "0", Activity.KEY_CHECKIN : String(activity.dateCheckIn), Activity.KEY_CHECKOUT : String(activity.dateCheckOut) ]

do {
    let jsonData = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(json, options: .PrettyPrinted)

    // create post request
    let url = NSURL(string: "https://...appspot.com/_ah/api/activityendpoint/v1/activity")!
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

    // insert json data to the request
    request.setValue("application/json; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.HTTPBody = jsonData


    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request){ data, response, error in
        if error != nil{
            print("Error -> \(error)")
            return
        }

        do {
            let result = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: []) as? [String:AnyObject]

            print("Result -> \(result)")

        } catch {
            print("Error -> \(error)")
        }
    }

    task.resume()
    return task
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: is the request sending async

Comment: @Logan the docs say that dataTaskWithRequest provides "a simple cancelable asynchronous interface to receiving data". So I would assume that this call is already asynchronous without dispatch_async

Answer (score 26):

Swift 5 answer:

```
let json: [String: Any] = ["key": "value"]

let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: json)

// create post request
let url = URL(string: "http://localhost:1337/postrequest/addData")! //PUT Your URL
var request = URLRequest(url: url)
request.httpMethod = "POST"
request.setValue("\(String(describing: jsonData?.count))", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")
request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
// insert json data to the request
request.httpBody = jsonData

let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
    guard let data = data, error == nil else {
        print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "No data")
        return
    }
    let responseJSON = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
    if let responseJSON = responseJSON as? [String: Any] {
        print(responseJSON) //Code after Successfull POST Request
    }
}

task.resume()
```

Comment: Correct answer. This worked in a copy-paste fashion for me.

Comment: Does this work for Swift 5.7?

Answer (score 15):

The following Swift 5 Playground code shows a possible way to solve your problem using `JSONSerialization` and `URLSession`:

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true

let url = URL(string: "http://localhost:8080/new")!
let jsonDict = ["firstName": "Jane", "lastName": "Doe"]
let jsonData = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: jsonDict, options: [])

var request = URLRequest(url: url)
request.httpMethod = "post"
request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
request.httpBody = jsonData

let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
    if let error = error {
        print("error:", error)
        return
    }

    do {
        guard let data = data else { return }
        guard let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String: AnyObject] else { return }
        print("json:", json)
    } catch {
        print("error:", error)
    }
}

task.resume()
```

Comment: Specifying "application/json" as ContentType is very important. otherwise the request will be executed as usual HTTP form. nice answer.

Answer (score 5):

```
let url = URL(string: "url")!
var request = URLRequest(url: url)
request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

request.httpMethod = "POST"



let postString = "ChangeAccordingtoyourdata=\(paramOne)&ChangeAccordingtoyourdata2=\(paramTwo)"
request.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
    guard let data = data, error == nil else {                                                 // check for fundamental networking error
        print("error=\(error)")
        return
    }

    if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {           // check for http errors
        print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
        print("response = \(response)")

        SVProgressHUD.showError(withStatus: "Request has not submitted successfully.\nPlease try after some time")
    }

    let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
    print("responseString = \(responseString)")

    SVProgressHUD.showSuccess(withStatus: "Request has submitted successfully.\nPlease wait for a while")
    DispatchQueue.main.async {



    // enter code

    }

}
task.resume()
```

Answer (score 5):

## Perfect nRewik answer updated to 2019:

Make the dictionary:

```
let dic = [
    "username":u,
    "password":p,
    "gems":g ]
```

Assemble it like this:

```
var jsonData:Data?
do {
    jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(
      withJSONObject: dic,
      options: .prettyPrinted)
} catch {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

Create the request exactly like this, notice it is a "post"

```
let url = URL(string: "https://blah.com/server/dudes/decide/this")!
var request = URLRequest(url: url)

request.setValue("application/json; charset=utf-8",
     forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
request.setValue("application/json; charset=utf-8",
     forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept") 
request.httpMethod = "POST"
request.httpBody = jsonData
```

Then send, checking for either a networking error (so, no bandwidth etc) or an error response from the server:

```
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
    guard let data = data, error == nil else {
        // check for fundamental networking error
        print("fundamental networking error=\(error)")
        return
    }

    if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {
        // check for http errors
        print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
        print("response = \(response)")
    }

    let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
    print("responseString = \(responseString)")
```

Fortunately it's now that easy.

Answer (score 4):

## Swift 5.5

As of Swift 5.5, we now have another alternative using `async`/`await`:

```swift
// Form the POST request:
let url = URL(string: "http://example.com/login")!
var request = URLRequest(url: url)
request.httpMethod = "POST"
request.setValue("application/json; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

// Use the async variant of URLSession to make an HTTP POST request:
let (data, response) = try await URLSession.shared.upload(for: request, from: requestData)
```

### Complete example:

```swift
struct LoginResponse: Decodable {
    let id: String
    let name: String
}

func login(_ username: String, _ password: String) async throws -> LoginResponse {
    struct RequestData: Encodable {
        let username: String
        let password: String
    }

    // Encode data to JSON to send in the POST request body:
    let encoder = JSONEncoder()
    let requestData = try encoder.encode(RequestData(username: username, password: password))

    // Form the POST request:
    let url = URL(string: "http://example.com/login")!
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.setValue("application/json; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

    // Use the async variant of URLSession to make an HTTP POST request:
    let (data, response) = try await URLSession.shared.upload(for: request, from: requestData)

    print("HTTPURLResponse:", response)
    print("The response body is:", String(decoding: data, as: UTF8.self))

    // Parse the JSON response:
    return try JSONDecoder().decode(LoginResponse.self, from: data)
}
```

### Usage

You must call it in an async context (so you can `await` it). One way is using a `Task`:

```swift
Task {
    do {
        let loginResponse = try await login("user1", "mypassword")
        print("Login successful for user with id:", loginResponse.id)
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

you can do something like this:

```
func HTTPPostJSON(url: String,  data: NSData,
    callback: (String, String?) -> Void) {

        var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: url)!)
        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
        request.addValue("application/json",forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.addValue("application/json",forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
        request.HTTPBody = data
        HTTPsendRequest(request, callback: callback)
}

func HTTPsendRequest(request: NSMutableURLRequest,
    callback: (String, String?) -> Void) {
        let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
            .dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
                (data, response, error) -> Void in
                if (error != nil) {
                    callback("", error.localizedDescription)
                } else {
                    callback(NSString(data: data,
                        encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)! as String, nil)
                }
        }

        task.resume()
}
//use
var data :Dictionary<String, AnyObject> = yourDictionaryData<--
var requestNSData:NSData = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(request, options:NSJSONWritingOptions(0), error: &err)!
HTTPPostJSON("http://yourPosturl..", data: requestNSData) { (response, error) -> Void in
    if error != nil{
        //error
        return;
    }

    println(response);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Swift4 - Apple Solution** "POST" and "Codable"

Uploading Data to a Website using  **request.httpmethod = "Post"** and **Codable Stucts**:

@see: [Listing 2 Configuring a URL request](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/url_loading_system/uploading_data_to_a_website#overview)

```
let userlogin = User(username: username, password: password, deviceid:UIDevice.current.identifierForVendor!.uuidString)

    guard let uploadData = try? JSONEncoder().encode(userlogin) else {
        print("Error UploadData: ")
        return
    }

    let urlUser = URL(string: APPURL.apiURL)!

    var request = URLRequest(url: urlUser)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

    var responseStatus = 0

    let task = URLSession.shared.uploadTask(with: request, from: uploadData) { data, response, error in
        if let error = error {
            let code = (error as NSError).code
            print("Error:\(code) : \(error.localizedDescription)")
            completion(code)
            return
        }  
      guard let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse else {
            print("Invalid response")
            return
        }
// do your response handling here ...
```

Comment: This answer wasn't really good - however the link there had some recent usable code in it. 

Comment: @Jonny: Its just the minimal configuration to get a POST, but you are right, there ist the codable part missing... my fault! I did update this by now.

Comment: Yes codable Structs is the future 

Comment: hi there! I found this answer, but cannot use it to solve my question, could someone help me here?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53598917/swift-4-how-to-pick-and-send-txt-file-via-post-request/53600049?noredirect=1#comment94067133_53600049

Answer (score 2):

No library required, simply use `URLSession`

here is an example:

```
let sampleData = ["key": "Value"]

var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://REPLACE.ME")!)
let urlSession = URLSession = URLSession(configuration: .default)

let encoder = JSONEncoder()
// inside a throwing function or wrap it in a doCatch block
let jsonData = try encoder.encode(sampleData)

urlRequest.httpMethod = "POST"
urlRequest.addValue("application/json",forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
urlRequest.httpBody = jsonData

let task = urlSession.dataTask(with: urlRequest) { data, response, error in
    let statusCode = (response as? HTTPURLResponse)?.statusCode
    print("‍♂️ \(statusCode)")
}

task.resume()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "http://yogpande.apphb.com/api/my/posttblhouse")!)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    let postString = "email=testname@gmail.com&password=1234567"
    request.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        guard let data = data, error == nil else {
            print("error=(error)")
            return
        }
        
        if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {     
            print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
            print("response = \(response)")
            
        }
        
        let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
        print("responseString = \(responseString)")
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

Comment: actually the jsonserialization method as body didn't work for me, but let postString = "email=testname@gmail.com&password=1234567"
    request.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8) worked .......!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

A combination of several answers found in my attempt to not use 3rd party frameworks like Alamofire:

```
let body: [String: Any] = ["provider": "Google", "email": "emailaddress@gmail.com"]
let api_url = "https://erics.es/p/u"
let url = URL(string: api_url)!
var request = URLRequest(url: url)

do {
    let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: body, options: .prettyPrinted)
    request.httpBody = jsonData
} catch let e {
    print(e)
}
    
request.httpMethod = HTTPMethod.post.rawValue
request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
    guard let data = data, error == nil else {
        print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "No data")
        return
    }
    let responseJSON = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
    if let responseJSON = responseJSON as? [String: Any] {
        print(responseJSON)
    }
}

task.resume()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// prepare json data
let mapDict = [ "1":"First", "2":"Second"]

let json = [ "title":"ABC" , "dict": mapDict ] as [String : Any]
let jsonData : NSData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: json) as NSData

// create post request
let url = NSURL(string: "http://httpbin.org/post")!
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url as URL)
request.httpMethod = "POST"

// insert json data to the request
request.httpBody = jsonData as Data


let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest){ data,response,error in
    if error != nil{
        return
    }
    do {
        let result = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as? [String:AnyObject]
        
        print("Result",result!)
        
    } catch {
        print("Error -> \(error)")
    }
}

task.resume()
```

Answer (score 0):

For a `Codable` / `Encodable` type in Swift 4+

Use a `JSONEncoder` to transform the object into `Data`:

```
let jsonObject = ... // Encodable or Codable

guard let jsonData = try? JSONEncoder().encode(jsonObject) else {
    fatalError("encoding error")
}
```

Then set that encoded object as the `httpBody` of the URLRequest:

```
var request = URLRequest(url: url)
request.httpMethod = "POST"
request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
request.httpBody = jsonData
```

Answer (score -1):

**Swift Clean Solution**

You can actually write JSON directly as the body of the request.

```
let url = URL(string: "https://endpointURL")!
var request = URLRequest(url: url)

request.httpMethod = "POST"
request.setValue("application/json; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

let jsonBody = 
"""
{
    "key": "value",
    "key": "value"
}
"""
    
request.httpBody = Data(jsonBody.utf8)
    
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        
    if let error = error {
        print("Post Request Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        return
    }
        
    guard let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse else {
        print("Invalid Response received from the server")
        return
    }
        
    print("Status Code: \(httpResponse.statusCode)")
        
    guard let responseData = data else {
        print("nil Data received from the server")
        return
    }
        
    //Decode your response here
    do {
        if let data = try? JSONDecoder().decode(CustomType.self, from: responseData) {
            print(data)
        } else {
            print("Error while decoding response")
            throw URLError(.badServerResponse)
        }
    } catch let error {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
.resume()
```

Comment: But the question is asking how to get a dictionary into the request as JSON. Simply hardcoding a JSON string ignores the whole point of the question.

Comment: @HangarRash I simply think writing the JSON directly is a better alternative, and personally I was converting JSON into a dictionary first and then encoding it for the body because I didn't know I could write JSON directly. If I did, I wouldn't use a dictionary in the first place. There is already suitable answer above for converting dictionary into data for people who really needs to use a dictionary, I simply want to provide other people who may think they have to use a dictionary to pass data for http request. Also the title is just "How to make HTTP Post request with JSON body in Swift?"

Comment: Plus, you can also string interpolate variables into it so it doesn't really have to be hard coding, although you can if you want.

Answer (score -2):

```
var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string:  "your URL")!)
request.httpMethod = "POST"


let postString =  String(format: "email=%@&lang=%@", arguments: [txt_emailVirify.text!, language!])
print(postString)

emailString = txt_emailVirify.text!

request.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)
request.addValue("delta141forceSEAL8PARA9MARCOSBRAHMOS", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
request.addValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")


let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
    guard let data = data, error == nil
        else
    {
        print("error=\(String(describing: error))")
        return
    }
    
    do
    {
        
        let dictionary = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments) as! NSDictionary
        print(dictionary)
        
        let status = dictionary.value(forKey: "status") as! String
        let sts = Int(status)
        DispatchQueue.main.async()
            {
                if sts == 200
                {
                    print(dictionary)
                

                }
                else
                {
                   self.alertMessageOk(title: self.Alert!, message: dictionary.value(forKey: "message") as! String)
                    
                    
                }
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        print(error)
    }
    
}
task.resume()
```

Answer (score -3):

```
func function()
{
    
    var parameters = [String:String]()
    let apiToken = "Bearer \(ApiUtillity.sharedInstance.getUserData(key: "vAuthToken"))"
    let headers = ["Vauthtoken":apiToken]
    
    parameters = ["firstname":name,"lastname":last_name,"mobile":mobile_number,"email":emails_Address]
    
    
    Alamofire.request(ApiUtillity.sharedInstance.API(Join: "user/edit_profile"), method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: URLEncoding.default,headers:headers).responseJSON { response in
        debugPrint(response)
        if let json = response.result.value {
            let dict:NSDictionary = (json as? NSDictionary)!
            print(dict)
            //                print(response)
            
            let StatusCode = dict.value(forKey: "status") as! Int
            
            if StatusCode==200
            {
                ApiUtillity.sharedInstance.dismissSVProgressHUDWithSuccess(success: "Success")
                let UserData = dict.value(forKey: "data") as! NSDictionary
                print(UserData)
                
            }
                
            else if StatusCode==401
            {
                let ErrorDic:NSDictionary = dict.value(forKey: "message") as! NSDictionary
                let ErrorMessage = ErrorDic.value(forKey: "error") as! String

            }
            else
            {

                let ErrorDic:NSDictionary = dict.value(forKey: "message") as! NSDictionary
                let ErrorMessage = ErrorDic.value(forKey: "error") as! String
            }
            
        }
        else
        {
            ApiUtillity.sharedInstance.dismissSVProgressHUDWithError(error: "Something went wrong")
        }
    }
```