# how to add parameter (for Drupal7 rating field) in http POST request, in swift 2

Tags: swift, drupal-7, http-post, nsurlsessiondatatask

I am a beginner, trying to code to submit a vote to the Drupal7 ratings field of a node with movie content.  Just as the node has a parameter for 'title', there is a parameter for 'rating-percent' which formats = "75%".
A GET request of json output from a view of nodes fetches the rating percent like this (together with many other fields).

```
            {
        node =             {
            Body = "synopsis here";
            "rating-percent" = "75%";
            Nid = 16620;
```

What do I add to this code to post the data value (eg 75%) to the 'rating-percent' parameter? Here is my attempt at the POST:

```
// Send HTTP PUT Request
let Nid = "1"

// Define server side script URL
let ratingscriptUrl = "https://example.com/node/"

// Add one parameter
 let urlWithParams = ratingscriptUrl + Nid

// Create NSURL Ibject
 let myUrl = NSURL(string: urlWithParams);

// Create URL Request
 let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL:myUrl!);

// Set POST request
 request1.HTTPMethod = "POST"

// Add parameters for 'ratings' field of node


// Execute HTTP Request
 let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
     data, response, error in

// Check for error
     if error != nil
  {
     print("error=\(error)")
     return
  }
```

Thank you so much for any help you can kindly give.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using SwiftyJSON here to convert my Dictionary into JSON

```
let result: Dictionary<String, AnyObject> = ["Body": "synopsis", "rating-percent" :  "75%"]
let json = JSON(result).rawString()
request.HTTPBody = json!.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
```

Also you have :

```
// Set POST request
 request1.HTTPMethod = "POST"
```

But you have name your request `request` and not `request1` but it must be a typo.

Comment: Thank you Manalalz. When I wrote request it brought up an error which I posted on stackexchange and the answer/solution was that it needed to be request1.HTTPMethod = "POST". I'm a beginner so am not sure why!
I will try this. Would like to clarify where in the code should it go? Is this the code to put beneath my comment to 'Add parameters' here?

Comment: It was because in your previous post you did declared : 
`let request1: NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
`  but here you declare it as request so it must be request.
For the request itself you can look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31937686/how-to-make-http-post-request-with-json-body-in-swift) there are examples of POST request in Swift with bodies, or you can also use [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire) it may be easier.

Comment: Thank you, I tried it. No errors come up in Xcode, but running it also gives no response. So I must still be missing something.