# xml posting in iOS without using frameworks?

Tags: ios

[How to make HTTP Post request with JSON body in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31937686/how-to-make-http-post-request-with-json-body-in-swift) like in this there are not using frameworks like this i need xml posting can any one help me...

Comment: How do you have your XML ? in string or in a file ?

Comment: I need it in objective c

Answer (score 1):

```
 NSError *error;

NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:configuration delegate:self delegateQueue:nil];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"Your SERVER"];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request addValue:@"application/xml" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
NSString *xmlString = @"<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\n<yourdata></yourdata>";
[request setHTTPBody:[xmlString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


NSURLSessionDataTask *postDataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

// handel response & error
}];

[postDataTask resume];
```

Use the above code to achieve what you want

Comment: Can u please send it in objective c currently am doing it in objective c

Comment: i updated to obj c. Accept the answer if it helped you