# Swift post json to Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, swift, afnetworking-3

I can't post json value to Rails from swift.

My Rails code is

```
def create

   @movie = Movie.new
   @movie.caption = movie_params["caption"]
   @movie.language = movie_params["language"]
   @movie.movie_file = movie_params["movie_file"]
   @movie.save
end


def movie_params
  params.require(:movie).permit(:caption, :language, :movie_file)
end
```

curl is working fine.

```
curl -v -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Accept: application/json' -X POST -d '{"movie":{"caption":"hoge","language":"TH","movie_file":"2016-10-16T14-30-30"}}' http://localhost:3000/movies.json
```

But how can I post json from swift.
xcode environment is
AFNetworking 3.0
SwiftyJSON 2.3.2

My swift code is

```
let dict: [String: AnyObject] = [
        "movie": [
            "caption": "hoge",
            "language":"",
            "movie_file":""
        ]
    ]

var json: String = ""
do {
// Dict -> JSON
        let jsonData = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(dict, options: []) //(*)options??

        json = NSString(data: jsonData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)! as String
    } catch {
        print("Error!: \(error)")
    }

    let strData = json.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)


    let manager: AFHTTPSessionManager = AFHTTPSessionManager()
    manager.requestSerializer.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = NSSet(object: "application/json") as? Set<String>

    let server_request = String(format: "%@/%@", self.server_url, request)

    let escapedRequest = server_request.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet())


    // here "jsonData" is the dictionary encoded in JSON data

    manager.POST(escapedRequest!, parameters: strData, progress: nil, success: { (operation, dataFromNetworking) -> Void in

        let jsonObj = JSON(dataFromNetworking!)
        callback(jsonObj)

        }, failure:{ (operation, error) -> Void in

    })
```

When I post this, I got error in Rails output

```
Started POST "/movies.json" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-10-20 10:40:52 +0700
Error occurred while parsing request parameters.
Contents:      =%3C7b226d6f%2076696522%203a7b226c%20616e6775%2061676522%203a22222c%2022636170%2074696f6e%20223a2268%206f676522%202c226d6f%207669655f%2066696c65%20223a2222%207d7d%3E

ActionDispatch::ParamsParser::ParseError (822: unexpected token at '=%3C7b226d6f%2076696522%203a7b226c%20616e6775%2061676522%203a22222c%2022636170%2074696f6e%20223a2268%206f676522%202c226d6f%207669655f%2066696c65%20223a2222%207d7d%3E'):
actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:53:in `rescue in parse_formatted_parameters'
actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:32:in `parse_formatted_parameters'
```

I'm really appreciated you help me. I'm struggling whole days.
Thanks in advance!

-TOM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
do {

    let jsonData = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(dict, options: .PrettyPrinted)

    // create post request
    let url = NSURL(string: "https://...your_host.com/movies.json")!
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

    // insert json data to the request
    request.setValue("application/json; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.HTTPBody = jsonData


    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request){ data, response, error in
        if error != nil{
            print("Error -> \(error)")
            return
        }

        do {
            let result = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: []) as? [String:AnyObject]

            print("Result -> \(result)")

        } catch {
            print("Error -> \(error)")
        }
    }

    task.resume()
    return task



} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Ref: [How to make HTTP Post request with JSON body in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31937686/how-to-make-http-post-request-with-json-body-in-swift)

Comment: Thank you so much Mr. Jayaprakash!

Comment: Then, why not you up vote my answer and mark it as correct answer? :-)

Comment: oh, I'm sorry. I didn't know the system. haha