# What does a "let-in" block mean in Swift?

Tags: swift, nsurlsession

Teaching myself Swift, and looking at this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31938246/7347751).

The part that's confusing me the most is this bit:

```
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, 
response, error in
    guard let data = data, error == nil else {
        print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "No data")
        return
    }
    let responseJSON = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, 
    options: [])
    if let responseJSON = responseJSON as? [String: Any] {
        print(responseJSON)
    }
}
```

I'll walk through the parts I do understand, and I'm hoping someone can help me fill in the gaps.

1. The `let task = ...` part is assigning a new `URLSessionDataTask` object to the variable `task` with the passed in `request` data. I get that.
2. `data`, `response`, and `error` (followed by `in`) seem to be placeholder parameters. Is this correct? And does the `in` keyword signify that these are input parameters? I read on Apple's documentation that they can be `in-out` parameters, so I'm thinking that's what this means. This mini-function of sorts accepts, rather than returns, something.
3. `guard let data = ...` this is a weird concept coming from other languages. From what I understand, the `guard` statement defines a set of `Bool`/boolean expressions, all of which have to be true, else the code inside the block is executed. So basically, if `data` cannot receive anything, and if `error` is `nil`/`null`, print an error message and return.
4. If all else is successful, print the JSON response and finish.

I guess the most foreign concept to me is the `let ... _, _, _ in` statement, since the syntax just looks really weird (placeholder parameters come after the opening `{`?)

I tried searching for documentation on this type of statement, and Apple compared it to a lambda expression in other languages. I can sort of see that with the `data, response, error` part.

So, if anyone can help clear a couple things up about this, it'd be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Your second question! “`in` keyword indicates that the definition of the closure’s parameters and return type has finished, and the body of the closure is about to begin.” From Apple's documentation

Comment: Look at the documentation for the `URLSession dataTask(with:completionHandler:)` method.

Comment: Then review the [Closures](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH11-ID94) chapter (with a focus on the [Trailing Closures](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH11-ID94) section) of the Swift book.

Comment: Here's another blog (Swift 3 but I believe no changes for Swift 4) about completion handlers that may be more relevant to the specifics in your question: https://grokswift.com/completion-handlers-in-swift/

Comment: Thanks all for your information. @dfd, this looks like a great blog, thanks much for sharing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `let ... _, _, _ in` thing can't really be discussed in this form, since it is not a single syntax (like an if statement or while loop), but a bunch of different things put together.

- `let task` declares a constant, whose type is inferred.
- `URLSession.shared.dataTask(...` calls a method in the `URLSession` class called `dataTask`. Its parameters are:

  - a request, which you have passed using a variable called `request`.
  - a closure, taking 3 parameters and returning nothing.
- Since the closure is the last parameter, the *trailing closure* syntax can be used here. This means that the closure can be written *outside* of the parentheses that are supposed to contain all the parameters. This is the closure that you passed in:

  ```
  { data, response, error in
      guard let data = data, error == nil else {
          print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "No data")
          return
      }
      let responseJSON = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, 
      options: [])
      if let responseJSON = responseJSON as? [String: Any] {
          print(responseJSON)
  }
  ```
- `data, response, error` are the closure's parameters. Again, their types are inferred.
- the word `in` is just part of the how-you-write-a-closure syntax. Think of it as saying "right, I'm now done with writing the parameters and capture list, moving on to what this closure's gonna do!"

Comment: OK, thank you very much, this makes a lot more sense now.