# How to pass parameter to the post request as a dictionary in swift ios?

Tags: ios, swift, postman

[image: dashBoardApplyListCriteria]
Here dashBoardApplyListCriteria parameter is a dictionary. How can pass dictionary as a parameter in swift ios.

Here is my code

```
let parameters: NSDictionary = [ "sessionId":sessionId, "jobId":jobId, "dashBoardApplyListCriteria":["1":["Recruiter"], "selectedBucketStatus":"Applies", "allJobsOrMyJobs":"AllJobs", "jobStatus":[0,1,2], "paginationStartNo":0, "paginationHowMuch":5], ] ]

    let parameters: [String: Any] =
        [
        "sessionId":sessionId,
        "jobId":jobId,
        "dashBoardApplyListCriteria":["actorList":["Recruiter"],
                                      "selectedBucketStatus":"Applies",
                                      "allJobsOrMyJobs":"AllJobs",
                                      "jobStatus":[0,1,2],
                                      "paginationStartNo":0,
                                      "paginationHowMuch":5],
        "applyListFilterCriteria":["appliesToBeSorted":["name":"dateApply","isAscending":true]]
    ]
```

let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters)

Comment: What did you try so far and what went wrong?

Comment: let parameters: NSDictionary = [
            "sessionId":sessionId,
            "jobId":jobId,
            "dashBoardApplyListCriteria":["1":["Recruiter"],
                                          "selectedBucketStatus":"Applies",
                                          "allJobsOrMyJobs":"AllJobs",
                                          "jobStatus":[0,1,2],
                                          "paginationStartNo":0,
                                          "paginationHowMuch":5],
            ]
        ]

Comment: Any solutions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make HTTP Post request with JSON body in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31937686/how-to-make-http-post-request-with-json-body-in-swift)

Comment: You seem to be using postman. Click on  `Code` in top right next to cookies and select `Swift` in top left of pop-up. It will give you the code.

Comment: I tried the swift code of postman but it did not work for me.

Comment: Any Solutions!!

Comment: How do you know it's not working? Could be because of App Transport Security? Because your code using URLSession is wrong? Because you don't know that the URLSession code is async and don't know how to manage it? Where did you put `jsonData` to `yourURLRequest.HTTPBody`? Is `jsonData` nil? You did a try?, no `catch`?

Comment: Thanks Larme. But the problem was with parameter, the dashboard ApplyList criteria was in string. I got the solutions after converting dashboard ApplyList criteria from dictionary to string. And converting whole parameter from "form data" format to "raw data" by appending "&".