# Beautiful Soup Find function equivalent for Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, beautifulsoup

I am working on a Swift app that sign in to my school website. In Python, the code bellow work well, but i stuck at finding equivalent for Swift.

Please help me find equivalent for BeautifulSoup's Find function in Swift. Thank you so much.

```
s = requests.Session()

try:
    r = s.get('url')
    r = BS(r.content, 'html5lib')

    sso_token = (r.find('input', {'name': 'lt'})).attrs['value']
    data = {'username': username,
            'password': password,
            'lt': sso_token,
            'execution': 'e1s1',
            '_eventId': 'submit',
            'submit': 'Login'}

    r = s.post('url', data=data)
```

Comment: I do believe you are looking for something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31938246/5698778), just change the dictionary parameters and you should be good to go.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I'll try that