# How to combine and split Data in swift

Tags: swift, nsdata

I am working on sending encrypted messages between two or more devices on swift.
I have 3 constants of type Data: **ephemeralPublicKey**, **ciphertext** and **signature**
I need to combine all 3 of them into 1 data, something like:

```
let data: Data = ephemeralPublicKey + ciphertext + signature
```

Then transmit this entire block of data to another device. On the new device I have to split it again back to ephemeralPublicKey, ciphertext and signature, so that I can use them to decrypt the message.
I am struggling from a couple of days with this and I still don't have idea how to do it.

Comment: Just a general hint, you almost certainly want to use Json for something like this.

Comment: (swift/ios handles JSON very well indeed - there's quite a bit to learn though, example https://stackoverflow.com/a/58634651/294884

Comment: Thank you for the idea